# Android ActionBar Not Appearing

Tags: android

I know, this sounds dumb, but bear with me.

I use the following

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"                
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
android:Theme.Holo"
```

When I run my app on 2.2 emulator, the menu button brings up my menu.

Whhen I run my app on 4.2 emulator, should the action bar not automatically be activated? I can see program icon + title. I have added some menu items like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/itemShare" android:title="@string/titleShare"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
```

I then have defined

```
onCreateOptionsMenu
```

all my activies inherit from.

Yet, I see nothing "action bar" icons when running my app in 4.2 emulator. I must be missing something obvious.

I am very new to Android and Eclipse, but I am slightly confused of above. The way I do it, should that not be the way to get pre/post honeycomb compability assuming one does not want to use ActionbarSherlock?

Answer (score 1):

> Whhen I run my app on 4.2 emulator, should the action bar not automatically be activated?

Yes.

> I can see program icon + title.

That is the action bar.

> Yet, I see nothing "action bar" icons when running my app in 4.2 emulator. I must be missing something obvious.

Your emulator has decided that there is insufficient room to show the icons, so they are in the overflow. Depending on your emulator configuration, you activate the overflow by pressing the MENU button or by pressing the ... affordance in the action bar on the right.

> The way I do it, should that not be the way to get pre/post honeycomb compability assuming one does not want to use ActionbarSherlock?

Yes.

Comment: The 4.2 emulator shows menu button. But it does not show any overflow button, nor does it show "ifRoom" menu items anywhere (on Action bar, overflow, menu) - it works as expected on my SG2 phone. I guess it is emulator config? It should show the "ifRoom" menu items *somewhere* right?

Comment: @Tom: Press the MENU button, and you should see your overflow items.

Comment: I have tried. I guess next step to take is to take a screenshot of it unless someone knows an emulator setting or similar.